# I am having difficulty printing range of unsigned long in c

Tags: c

I am trying to print the range of UNSIGNED LONG datatype using the ***limits.h*** library with following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

   int main()
   {
   printf("The range of UNSIGNED LONG =   %lu  \n", ULONG_MAX);
   return 0;
   }
```

**The value returned is : 4294967295**

This value seems to be wrong,

what is the correct place holder to be used for printing the range of UNSIGNED LONG?

how do i correct the above code snippet.

Comment: That looks perfectly right to me.

Comment: Why does it seem wrong?  `2^32 - 1 = 4294967295`

Comment: Why do you think the value is wrong?

Comment: Were you assuming that a `long` should have a 64 bit width?

Comment: when i print the range of unsigned int and unsigned long they are exactly the same,
I presumed that range of unsigned long would be greater than unsigned int .
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: The rule is `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Isn't `long long` guaranteed to gave at least 64 bits?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah.  I removed that part though as there are a few other requirements like `int` mandated to hold a 16 bit twos compliment value and  and `long` mandated to hold a 32 bit twos compliment value.  Oh, and char has to be 1.

Comment: @EdmundCarvalho That's fine.  `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` allows for them to be the same value.

Comment: This hierarchy works in one direction only. The standard [mandates](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) the minimal magnitude of the range, but not the maximal.

Comment: I have concluded that range of unsigned int and unsigned long are the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok I understood thanks ,
I think my previous comment got deleted by mistake .

Comment: The range of unsigned int and unsigned long are the same *in your implementation*.

Answer (score 1):

The value you're getting back is valid.

From Appendix E of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1* The contents of the header **limits.h** are given below, in alphabetical order. The minimum magnitudes shown shall be replaced by
>   implementation-defined magnitudes with the same sign. The values shall
>   all be constant expressions suitable for use in #if preprocessing
>   directives. The components are described further in 5.2.4.2.1.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> #define UINT_MAX 65535
> #define ULONG_MAX 4294967295
> ```

The size of a `unsigned long` is implementation defined, but has a minimum range of values it can represent.  The value you're getting is within that range.  Other types such as `unsigned int` have their own minimums.

Typically (but not always), compilers on a 32-bit OS will have a 32 bit `long`, while compilers on a 64-bit OS will have a 64-bit `long`.  Most likely, you're on a 32 bit system with a 32 bit compiler.

Comment: _"compilers on a 64-bit OS will have a 64-bit long"_ Said no Windows developer ever. :P

Comment: Typically, compilers on a 32-bit OS or 64-bit Windows will have 32-bit `long`, while 64-bit compilations on a 64-bit POSIX-ish system (Unix and relatives) will have 64-bit `long` (a 32-bit compilation on a 64-bit Unix-like system will probably use 32-bit `long` still).

Comment: Thank you for the information .

Comment: @EdmundCarvalho Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.